# How to read the following datasheet of a sensor?

Tags: sensor, datasheet, transducer, pressure

I wanted to write about static and dynamic characteristics of the Honeywell pressure 19mm transducer. I found my [sensors datasheet](https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-19mm-series-isolated-pressure-sensors-product-sheet-009132-3-en.pdf) but could not find the following characteristics mentioned in the datasheet directly.Could you help me know if any of the below are mentioned in the datasheet.

Characteristics : Accuracy, Precision, Sensitivity, Linearity, Resolution, Reproducibility, Repeatability, Threshold, Tolerance, Range, Stability, Drift, Hysteresis, Speed of Response, Measuring Lag, Fidelity, Dynamic Error, Noise.

I found some like Time Response, Range, Repeatibility because they were directly written.

Data Sheet Link : https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-19mm-series-isolated-pressure-sensors-product-sheet-009132-3-en.pdf

Comment: The desired parameters exist in the datasheet in the performance section. It just doesn't give directly.

Comment: You can't write anything to these analogue bridge pressure sensors. You stick a supply on it and use an ADC (or similar) to read the output voltage.

Comment: Why are you interested in these particular characteristics? What are the actual requirements of your application?

Comment: This strikes me as a homework assignment.  What have you been able to figure out so far?  Other than things that are directly written there.

Comment: @NickAlexeev You guessed it right. I didn't figure out much but enough to finish homework.

Answer (score 2):

Some seem redundant, but this should cover most of it.

Accuracy: How much can you trust that reading X is exactly X

Precision: How small of a step of the output is generally meaningful, like saying you have 2.0000 hands does not really add anything,

Sensitivity: How small of a change on the input will cause the output to change

Linearity: If you take a reading at a low value, and a high value, how likely is a value in the middle of them to be exactly the same, as an alternate how straight a line would it draw if you plotted input vs output

Resolution: the smallest possible change in the output, generally smaller than precision.

Repeatability: You start at value X on the input, you change the input to some other far away value, you then go back to value X on the input, how close will the output be to the original you records at input X.

Range: How large can you measure between the smallest output value and the largest

Stability: At different temperatures and supply voltages how much will the output vary

Drift: Over time, be it days, months or years, does the output value drift higher or lower than original, and by how much.

Hysteresis: what is the difference in output between increasing the input to a value, and decreasing the input to a value.

Speed of Response: How quickly the output will change to a change in the input

Fidelity: Related to precision,

Noise: Provided the input does not change, how much might the output move up or down from that value on average over a short time period, this may be due to supply noise coupling in or thermal noise generated in the device.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear now about the terms. But I could not find most of the above terms in the datasheet. Is there a different technical alias used or something? For example, I couldn't find sensitivity mentioned.